# Custom fields with wordpress

Tags: custom-field

I've a custom field for a date, written like: yyyy-mm-dd

How can I extract only the **day** to display in PHP ? For the moment, I display the full date:`'. get_post_meta($post->ID, 'event_start_date', true).'`

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function:

```
$date = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'event_start_date', true);
$day = date('d', strtotime($date)); //01-31
```

Another way will be [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php):

```
$date = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'event_start_date', true);
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date);
$day  = $date->format('d');
```

Comment: Thanks ! But it displays **01** value every time.

Comment: What do you mean? this should display the day (01-31) depending on the meta field `event_start_date`. So this for the same `$post->ID` will always display the same value.